# Google Apps Script "Upgraded Authorisation Experience" and OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have been playing with the new Admin SDK in conjunction with the "upgraded authorisation experience" and wondered if someone has and experience/examples on how to use it. From what I have read, if you upgrade the authorisation experience you shouldn't need to use OAuth 2.0 and get a client ID and secret from the API console.

When you upgrade the authorisation, the API console entry is automatically created so you just have to turn on Admin SDK. Your app should then run simply using your own admin credentials.

Have I misunderstood this and if so, what is the benefit of the new authorisation experience?

I can use the Admin SDK just fine if I create a client ID and secret in the API console but this is using OAuth 2.0 then.

If someone has an example of how to use the admin sdk with OAuth 1.0 i could have a look at it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need get your tokens and API key...

Take from the [Directory API documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing?hl=en):

> If your application has certain unusual authorization requirements, such as logging in at the same time as requesting data access (hybrid) or domain-wide delegation of authority (2LO), then you cannot currently use OAuth 2.0 tokens. In such cases, you must instead use OAuth 1.0 tokens and an API key. You can find your application's API key in the Google APIs Console, in the Simple API Access section of the API Access pane.

If you are looking for an oAuth2 example with GAS, Arun has a nice example he posted on GitHub, see the SO posting: [How to authorize with oauth 2.0 from appscript to Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533565/how-to-authorize-with-oauth-2-0-from-appscript-to-google-apis)
Sorry, I don't have any oAuth1 example to interface with the new APIs.