# how to use googleapis from apps script

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

**My intent:**

I want to call Google Calendar's API [acl.list()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list#auth) from a [google script](https://script.google.com)
using [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29) function.

**Problem:**

My Google script it self has oauth token when it runs. Problem is that UrlFetchApp.fetch() is a separate http request which requires oauth token to work.

**Question:**

How do I reuse token used by my (already authorized) apps-script in http request called manually from that script. Is it possible? If not, then how do I generate token for this request?

**Rationale:**

The [ContactsApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) is pleasant to work with but it does not have needed ACL functionality yet.

**My (not working) code:**

```
function pleaseHelp() {
  var calId = "MY_CORRECT_CALENDAR_ID";
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + calId + "/acl";
  var data = {
    "foo" : "foo data",
    "bar" : "data bar...",
  };
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : payload
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

gives exception: "401 Login Required" obviously...

*Thanks in advance for any help.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try https://gist.github.com/entaq/4079885 and [How to authorize with oauth 2.0 from appscript to Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533565/how-to-authorize-with-oauth-2-0-from-appscript-to-google-apis/13534161#13534161)

Answer (score 1):

you can attach the token to the call you are making.

for example: 
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{cal id}/acl?**access_token='yourtoken'**

Comment: how do I get the token?