# Google Apps Script - Run script as a another user (with password)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a script which transfers the ownership of a file to another user, this works when the user who runs the scripts is the owner of the file that is going to be transferred.

[setOwner(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#setOwner(String))

Would it be possible to accomplish this without having to login as the owner of the file to run the script? I have the email and the password of the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Not as straightforward, you'll have to [get access with oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533565/how-to-authorize-with-oauth-2-0-from-appscript-to-google-apis) and use the Drive API to [update the permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update).

Never worked with oauth2/Drive API so can't give you any examples.